# Add-on loading problem

Tags: add-on

I am just getting started writing a multi-file add-on for Blender 2.93. I can run the below inside a single script inside Blender and get a button added to the user interface:

```
bl_info = {
    "name": "Simple operator",
    "author": "",
    "version": (1, 0),
    "blender": (2, 80, 0),
    "location": "View3D > Add > Mesh > New Object",
    "description": "Initial test",
    "warning": "",
    "doc_url": "",
    "category": "Add Mesh",
}

import bpy  # noqa


class SimpleOperator(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Tooltip"""
    bl_idname = "object.simple_operator"
    bl_label = "Simple Object Operator"

    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        return context.active_object is not None

    def execute(self, context):
        bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_monkey_add()
        return {'FINISHED'}


class Layout(bpy.types.Panel):
    """Creates a Panel in the scene context of the properties editor"""
    bl_label = "Layout Demo"
    bl_idname = "SCENE_PT_layout"
    bl_space_type = 'PROPERTIES'
    bl_region_type = 'WINDOW'
    bl_context = "scene"

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout

        scene = context.scene

        # Large button
        layout.label(text="Simple operator")
        row = layout.row()
        row.scale_y = 3.0
        row.operator("object.simple_operator")


def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(Layout)
    bpy.utils.register_class(SimpleOperator)


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(Layout)
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(SimpleOperator)

register()
```

To simulate a multi-file add-on I just pasted this code to a file _*init_*.py placed into a zip file

```
my_plugin_name.zip
  |my_plugin_name
        |__init__.py
```

Loading this plugin by *Edit --> Preferences --> Add-ons --> Install* and selecting "my_plugin_name.zip" yields no visible change to the GUI. In the console I however I see

```
reloading addon: my_plugin_name 1623853552.3498223 1623853837.9650578 '/home/username/.config/blender/2.93/scripts/addons/my_plugin_name/__init__.py'
Modules Installed () from '/home/username/my_plugin_name.zip' into '/home/username/.config/blender/2.93/scripts/addons'
```

So it does seem _*init_*.py is loaded, but nothing happens still. The execution of _*init_*.py seems to happen before the install, which is a bit strange. The script is correctly copied to '/home/username/.config/blender/2.93/scripts/addons/my_plugin_name/_*init_*.py'.  Ideas?

I am using Ubuntu 20.04 in case that matters.

Comment: what happens when you close blender and reload? The blender dev extensions to VS Code made a world of difference, a bit tricky to set up but totally worth it

Comment: May or may not be issue ... Take out the `register()` call. Or put it in the standard `if __name__ == "__main__":` conditional. The register method of the module is to be called  when the addon is enabled, not when it is imported.

Comment: I tried closing and reloading several times without any success. Tried different approaches for calling `register()` too. I just got the the blender development extension to work, after some file permission problems. It is really good, but I also need to be able to ship this extension stand-alone to people sooner or later.